Proof of Grothendieck's Semistability Criterion for Elliptic Curves
We have the following result:
Let $E/\mathbb Q$ be an elliptic curve and let $p$ be a prime. Then $E$ is semistable at $p$ if and only if $\rho_{E,\ell}|_{I_p}$ is unipotent for some (all) prime(s) $\ell \neq p$. Here $I_p$ is an inertia group at $p$.
I have only ever encountered proofs of this result in the case $E$ is a general abelian variety. See, for example, Conrad, Semistable Reduction for Abelian Varieties. I am looking for either a reference or a typed up answer containing a (hopefully simpler) full proof of this just in the case $E$ is an elliptic curve, if such a thing exists.
